# Google chrome mail notifiers

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

For a long time I've been using a handy gmail notifier extension for google chrome, but due to system reinstall I've discovered an issue that there is no any handy notifier nowadays in webstore.

So the question is: what google chrome extension do you use to notify about new gmail letters?

Currently I've found only https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adlgnpfgagimgadbaboilkbdnhbpegmd but it is really terrible

**UPD**:

To be precise - this is the extension I liked much:
[image]

It was hosted at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gffjhibehnempbkeheiccaincokdjbfe but isn't available anymore :-(

Comment: Seems to be available again now

Comment: @Colin Pickard: interesting if it's better than https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use gmail checker https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff

Works perfectly.

Comment: The bad thing about it is that it doesn't support several emails checking